# CSS grid dynamic columns - grid-template-columns

Tags: css, user-interface, css-grid

I'm new to CSS and facing an issue while creating dynamic grid-template-columns. I would like the boxes to be all the way to the right regardless of how many values i get from API. API data is being simulated by the random number implemenatation in TS file.

Here is the stackblitz link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-map-keyvalue-7a2kr9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss

Thank you.

I tried using [ngStyle] in html and apply styling based on how many values I get from API but I do not like this approach.

```
<div class="container" [ngStyle]="{
     'grid-template-columns':
     tableValues == 1
     ? '10fr repeat(1, 1fr)'
     : tableValues == 2
     ? '10fr repeat(2, 1fr)'
     : tableValues == 3
     ? '10fr repeat(3, 1fr)'
     : tableValues == 4
     ? '10fr repeat(4, 1fr)'
     : null
}">
```

Comment: Using the flex system instead a grid can do the trick, there is a reason behind you are not using it?

Comment: no reason I haven't tried that, I will try to see if I can use flexbox for this issue.

Comment: To obtain the desired result you should set the boxes parent item as display flex, then the css property `justify-content:end` will move all the child boxes to the end/right side of the parent